# Kendo Grid column HTML formatting not working when column is initially hidden

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid in ASP.Net Razor. For the columns that are **not** hidden on the initial display, the HtmlAttributes "works"; that is, the values are shown as formatted numerical values, aligned to the right.

However, if a another column, otherwise formatted in exactly the same way, is hidden on the initial display, and then added to the grid by the User (by using the column header column picker) - the formatting is not fully utilized; I am seeing the values in the column aligned to the **left**.

Here's two column from the grid I'm having the problem with.

How can I get the HTML formatting to always apply, regardless of initial visibility?

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.EarnedCost)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).Format("{0:N2}")
                .ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum, 'N2')#")
                .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.PayHours).Hidden(true)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" }).Format("{0:N2}")
                .ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(sum, 'N2')#")
                .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right;" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, had to do it using JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide Columns
    var grid = $("#rgInventory").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.hideColumn("Patent");
    grid.hideColumn("Customs");
});
```